# Flutter Hoow add share this App via Phone apps?

Tags: flutter, share

Hi how i can make a Link in my app and if the user click on it open this menu with email whatsapp etc and the user can share a link with my Play Store Link to friends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [share](https://pub.dev/packages/share/example) package. Here is the full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:share/share.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(DemoApp());
}

class DemoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  DemoAppState createState() => DemoAppState();
}

class DemoAppState extends State<DemoApp> {

  // Your own PlayStore or AppStore Link
  String appStoreLink = '<link of app store>';
  String subject = '<subject>';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Share Plugin Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Share Plugin Demo'),
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
               
                  const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0)),
                  Builder(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return RaisedButton(
                        child: const Text('Share'),
                        onPressed: () => _onShare(context),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }

  
  _onShare(BuildContext context) async {
  
    final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
  
      await Share.share(appStoreLink,
          subject: subject,
          sharePositionOrigin: box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size);
    }
  
}
```